# How can assign author name as term of a custom post type programmatically?

Tags: wordpress

I need to set author name of a custom post type as its term of taxonomy Programmatically.
I try by this code. but I manually set term to author name in admin.
this shortcode needs term of posts. I want to set author name as term by program, then insert it in shortcode.

```
 <?php



     $cat=get_the_author_meta('user_login');



    ?>

     <?php echo do_shortcode("[cptapagination custom_post_type='product' cptataxname='product_cat' cptacatname='$cat' post_limit='4'] ");?>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: instead of shortcode you can use `publish_post` action hook and run the function which executes when post published :

Comment: Hi. this shortcode is from a plugin that ajax paginate posts type by category. I want to paginate posts by author in authors page.

Comment: @Manjunath I would be better to use `save_post`.

Comment: @Bas van Dijk yes you can but save_post will update each and every time when posts are edited. So i suggested publish_post but yes ut totally depends on your requirement :)

Comment: @Farhang i think you could use url for that purpose using custom template pages. For example get_query_object() can be used